# How to make a Greasemonkey script that Automatically Clicks on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I try to make a script that click automatically the "CONFIRM" button when it appear on Jango.com

I tried:

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
```

But it does not work :(

Here's a screenshot with the button and code from the button

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `onload` event handler to your Javascript, like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].onload = function(this) {
    this.click();
}
```

More on this topic: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work :( 

The part of the page with the button load only after I press the "thumb up or down to confirm my selection.

Comment: You can use `window.onload = function(this) { ... }` instead.